# Installation with MinimalCD: "Couldn't download package"

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server to a VirtualBox virtual machine using the 32bit MinimalCD. During the step "Install the base system", I get several warnings from packages that cannot be downloaded, like `dmsetup`, `ntpdate`, `passwd` and `xbd-data`.

EDIT: the actual packages that cannot be downloaded seem to differ from day to day. When I retried today the error popped up for entirely different packages, and the aformentioned packages downloaded fine.

[image: Debootstrap warning]

This happens consistently in both the standard and the expert installation. I also tried different archive mirrors (US, GB and BE). All the other packages download fine. The strange thing is that when I retry the same step after it failed, everything passes fine from the second run.

Is this a common problem? Is there any way to avoid this step failing?

Comment: Which version are you trying to install 32 or 64? VirtualBox or VMware?

Comment: 32bit to VirtualBox, edited it in my question.

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday, when I installed server, I ended up installing the 64bit version using VMWare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, my problem was resolved as soon as I changed my network adapter to **bridged mode** instead of **NAT** in the virtual machine settings in VirtualBox.

I never experienced any other connection issues with NAT mode however. It also might be specific to the Mac version of VirtualBox (happened on different Macs on different internet connections to me).

Comment: If it has resolved your problem, then feel free to accept your answer. That is the norm here.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I will but I need to wait 13 more hours to accept it :)

Comment: My ignorance, didn't look at the time you posted your answer...